# Docked bottom does not working on Google Chrome on iPhone in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2, docking

I have simple view that extends from Ext.form.Panel and have three items. 
First item is toolbar with property docked: 'top', the second is fieldset and the third item is toolbar but it's docked to bottom. 
This view looks ok, but when I open it on iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 (both with iOS 6) with Google Chrome, the third item is gone.

Can sameone explain why the toolbar that is docked to bottom is not shown only on Google Chrome on iPhone ?

```
Ext.define("TestApp.view.Test", {
    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
    requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
    alias: "widget.testview",
    config: {
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: "toolbar",
                docked: "top",
                title: "Title",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: "button",
                        ui: "back",
                        text: "back",
                        itemId: "backBtn"
                    }
                ]
            },
            { xtype: "fieldset",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'title',
                        label: 'Title'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textareafield',
                        name: 'description',
                        label: 'Description'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: "toolbar",
                docked: "bottom",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: "button",
                        iconCls: "trash",
                        iconMask: true,
                        itemId: "deleteBtn"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I have a similar problem that may be the same as yours. On chrome, the navigation bar (or 'omnibar' as they call it) pushes down the app space and the bottom gets cut off.

You'll know this is the same problem if going to full screen mode unhides your bottom bar. Full screen is typically achieved in chrome by scrolling up. However, if the item docked at the top is not scrollable, you can't hide it from there. Try to hide it on the loading screen. For more information, Google search 'ios chrome fullscreen' or 'ios chrome hide navigation bar'. There are also ways to do it within your application.